# Do planetary radio frequency change upon alignments?

Tags: planet, radio-astronomy

If Neptune would align Uranus, would the radio frequency perceived on Earth increase?

Are the radio antennas on NM capable of getting the 2 different radio frequencies feom both planets or would they get a bigger range of frequencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the electromagnetic radiation (in the radio spectrum) produced by the planets themselves, then the answer is no.

BTW, not all planets generate a lot of radio EM. Jupiter does generate some amount, but the other planets are quite a bit more quiet. Still, a very small amount is probably generated by most planets out there.

In any case, this is a strictly local phenomenon. Local conditions within and on that planet predominate in driving the production of radio EM.

By comparison, distances between planets are HUGE. Whether they are "aligned" or not is of no importance to what happens on the surface. Anyway, they appeared "aligned" only to us, on Earth, and even then the "alignment" is always imperfect (they are never exactly on a line).

Shortly: no.

Comment: Good that's exactly what I wanted to know!